# Terraform to create autoscale VM rule setting based on Disk Write Operations/Sec or Disk Write Bytes

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-vm-scale-set

Based on the [autoscale rule criteria](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview#autoscale-rule-criteria) I am trying to create a terraform `azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting` rule which increase/decreases VM nodes based on **Disk Write Operations/Sec** or **Disk Write Bytes**. The metric trigger looks like the following:

```
rule {
     metric_trigger {
            operator           = "GreaterThan"
            threshold          = 50
            time_grain         = "PT1M"
            statistic          = "Average"
            time_window        = "PT5M"
            metric_name        = "Disk Write Operations/Sec"
            time_aggregation   = "Average"
    }
}
```

However, I believe this is not the right syntax since once applying the terraform script it never creates this rule. On the other hand replacing the rule with **"Percentage CPU"** works fine. Have anyone created any metrics other than **"Percentage CPU"**? Can you help figuring out what is the right way to do it in `terraform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack the `metric_resource_id`. You could try the following example, this works on my side.

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "test" {
  name                = "myAutoscaleSetting"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  target_resource_id  = "${azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.test.id}"

  profile {
    name = "defaultProfile"

    capacity {
      default = 1
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 10
    }

    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "Disk Write Operations/Sec"
        metric_resource_id = "${azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.test.id}"
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "GreaterThan"
        threshold          = 75
      }

      scale_action {
        direction = "Increase"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }

    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "Disk Write Operations/Sec"
        metric_resource_id = "${azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.test.id}"
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "LessThan"
        threshold          = 25
      }

      scale_action {
        direction = "Decrease"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
  }

  notification {
    email {
      send_to_subscription_administrator    = true
      send_to_subscription_co_administrator = true
      custom_emails                         = ["admin@contoso.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: In my case the Disk Write Operations/Sec 's  `metric_resource_id` will be the same as the one for Percentage CPU. Does that mean that `metric_name` is what Azure uses to determine which metric actually to use?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the `metric_name`, any update on this thread?